# List within Lists

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following user control for a contact list

```
<UserControl.Content>
        <Border BorderBrush="LightBlue" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" Height="300" Margin="0,0,-1,0">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" x:Name="tStack" Grid.Column="0">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <MenuItem MouseDoubleClick="MenuItem_MouseDoubleClick_1" Header="{Binding Username}">
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="C:\Users\JR-WORK\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\itControl Chat\itControl Chat\Images\green-bullet.png" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Username}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Border>
    </UserControl.Content>
```

This works great and shows one menu item for each `user` in my `ObservableCollection` of `Users`.  Now I want to add another `ObservableCollection` of user groups, like Friends, Groups, Favorites, whatever.  How do I layer in another binding to create a list within a list?  Do I need to create another `UserControl` that contains this one as a data template?

Answer (score 0):

If the list within a list is a property of the items of the parent list (i.e. the user), then you can just add another ItemsControl to the template for user.